# Check if a global property/function has been overwritten in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, overwrite, global-object

JavaScript makes it easy to overwrite properties and functions of the global object. I'd like to find a way to check if the original version of a global property has been replaced.

Consider someone putting this in their HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.encodeURIComponent = eval;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

If myscript.js calls the encodeURIComponent function somewhere, it will now behave unpredictably. So is there a way I can check inside myscript.js if someone has overwritten that function before I use it?

Answer (score 8):

The only thing I know is a straightforward approach with analysis of string representation of the function. Normally, the code

```
window.encodeURIComponent.toString()
```

should produce something like this:

```
function encodeURIComponent() { [native code] }
```

which can be easily parsed for key info `function encodeURIComponent`.

If the function was overwritten by `eval`, as in your example, you'll get:

```
function eval() { [native code] }
```

In general, for checking `window` properties, you can create a fake iframe and compare `window.[property].toString()` with `iframe.contentWindow.[property].toString()`. If the comparison gives `false`, the property has been changed.

Comment: This is a really clever and cross-browser way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks Stan. Do you also know how to ensure that the toString property of `eval` hasn't been overwritten with something like `function () { return "function encodeURIComponent() { [native code] }"; }`?

Comment: instead of parsing and calling `toString` you can simply do this `window.encodeURIComponent.name`.. ANYWAY there is more preciese method to achive this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10266791/474290

Comment: @ft1: I'm afraid, I don't know a solution.

Comment: For anyone looking to use this in a security context, you cannot rely on this check unless you can ensure there is no malicious code run before it. A malicious library can overwrite properties and render this check useless.

Answer (score 3):

One interesting way to do this inside one script is to compare function prototype

By default - `typeof window.encodeURIComponent.prototype === "undefined"`

But if someone redefines this function by

`window.encodeURIComponent = function() { eval(); }` 
we will get

`typeof window.encodeURIComponent.prototype === "Object"`

PS: this method is more reliable then others, but it won't give you 100% gurante. JavaScript is all objects and all in runtime.. just live with this..

**UPDATE**
you can combine both methods.. mine and @Stans..

this example don't work because I wasn't using `eval` - eval Is also having prototype "undefined" by default.. so you can do this

```
window.encodeURIComponent.name === "encodeURIComponent" 
//to make shure that user won't use EVAL 
&& typeof window.encodeURIComponent.prototype === "undefined" 
//to make shure that user won't use self defined function
```

Comment: Ai_boy, I can't seem to reproduce that. `typeof window.encodeURIComponent.prototype` is `"undefined"` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is browser specific and definitely will not work for non-functions, but:

Calling a function's `toString` method should produce something like:

```
Chrome:

"function encodeURIComponent() { [native code] }"

Firefox:

"function encodeURIComponent() {
    [native code]
}"

IE 7/8/9:
"
function encodeURIComponent() {
    [native code]
}
"
```

Observe that the function's name matches the property's name, and its body is replaced by "`[native code]`". The idea is to remove all whitespace from this string and compare it to the expected result, `"functionxxx(){[nativecode]}"`.

I have no idea if it works for all browsers/functions, that's trial and error:

```
var pattern = 'function' + propertyName + '(){[nativecode]}';
var func = window[propertyName].toString();
if(func.replace(/\s+/g, '') !== pattern) {
    throw new Error("Property window." + propertyName + " has been modified!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function isNativeWindowProperty(propertyName) {
    var result = false;
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = 'javascript:;';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iframe);
    if (window[propertyName].toString() === iframe.contentWindow[propertyName].toString()) {
        // check window[propertyName].toString override
        if (window[propertyName].toString.toString() === iframe.contentWindow[propertyName].toString.toString()) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    return result;
};

console.log(isNativeWindowProperty('alert'));  // true

window.alert = function() {};
console.log(isNativeWindowProperty('alert'));  // false

window.alert.toString = function() {
    return 'function alert() { [native code] }';
};
console.log(isNativeWindowProperty('alert'));  // false
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some text to explain how your code answers the queston?

Comment: Interesting approach - although `document.createElement` could itself have been monkey-patched and might tinker with contents of the created iframe...

Comment: I developed this idea and some others into a script that scans the `window` object for modified constructors and class-methods - I posted the result in a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63778711/283851).

Answer (score 0):

There is an EASY way to do it in JavaScript :) But you have to have access to the HTML, so you can't use this method inside of one script..

function is an OBJECT.. so we can save a link to an object and just compare those links. Just think of a function like it a simple object. How can you compare objects?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = window.encodeURIComponent;  // a === window.encodeURIComponent -> true
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.encodeURIComponent = eval; // a === window.encodeURIComponent -> false
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js">
    if (a !== window.encodeURIComponent) 
    {
        throw new Error('Someone redefined function');
    }
</script>
```