# Is it possible to find out if function navigator.plugins has been overwritten

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Im working on a little script to detect phantomjs crawler on our website. One  way to detect phantoms is to ask for the installed plugins with.

> navigator.plugins

But its possible to overwirte the function. How would you detect if the function has been manipulated? Is there a way to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here.
[Check if a global property/function has been overwritten in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266080/check-if-a-global-property-function-has-been-overwritten-in-javascript)

But the short answer is you can't. If you write a function to test another function then someone could also overwrite your test.